# TYPO3: show/hide specific menu items depending on current language

Tags: menu, typo3, typoscript

TYPO3 version 6.1

My page structure:

```
root
  page1
    subpage1-1
    subpage_only_for_fr_1-2
    subpage_only_for_de_1-3
  page2
    subpage2-1
    subpage2-2
```

My menu structure is the same (except root item):

```
  page1
    subpage1-1
    subpage_only_for_fr_1-2
    subpage_only_for_de_1-3
  page2
    subpage2-1
    subpage2-2
```

My menu TS is:

```
LEFTNAV = HMENU
LEFTNAV {
    1 = TMENU
    1 {
        wrap = <ul>|</ul>
        NO = 1
        NO {
            wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
            stdWrap.field = title
        }
        ACT = 1
        ACT {
            wrapItemAndSub = <li class="active">|</li>
            stdWrap.field = title
        }
    }
    2 < .1
}
```

I have an one additional language for my site (default = deutsch, additional = french):

```
[globalVar=GP:L=0]
  config.sys_language_uid = 0
  config.language = de
[global]
[globalVar=GP:L=2]
  config.sys_language_uid = 2
  config.language = fr
[global]
```

I want to show/hide some pages in my menu depending on current language.

For example, if user switch language to **French**, i want to show page **subpage_only_for_fr_1-2** in menu and hide **subpage_only_for_de_1-3**. And vice verca.

How can i accomplish that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved! Here is the simple solution:

Just need to check out fields under the **Language** section on **Behaviour** tab (when eyou edit page):

```
Language
Localization 

 Hide default translation of page
 Hide page if no translation for current language exists
```

1) For fields that i need only in Deutsch language, i make checkbox "Hide page if no translation for current language exists" active. Note: you shouldn't add any translations for them in french.

2) For fields that i need only in French, i make checkbox "Hide default translation of page" active. Because it is default language.

And TYPO3 will be hide/show needed pages depending on current language correctly!

Comment: There is a very convenient way of setting the second checkbox option as a default for all pages: Just add `$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['FE']['hidePagesIfNotTranslatedByDefault'] = '1';` to your localconf or set it in the install tool. Thus, you don't need to set for every page separately.

Comment: Thanks, i saw this solution. By the thing is that i need it NOT for all my pages, just for specific.